# How to run nestjs in digital ocean with nginx?

Tags: nestjs, digital-ocean

After installing Nginx and running it.

```
 `location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}`
```

but it wants not run in the droplet Ip address, it's just run locally.